# Разделитель в числе после "запятой"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Чтобы установить разделитель в целой части числа можно использовать:

```
select to_char(123456.987654, '99G99G99G99D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='', ''')
from   dual
```

> 12 34 56,987654

Но как сделать так, чтобы разделители были после запятой?

Формат типа `'99G99G99G99D99G99G99'` выдает ошибку:

> ORA-01481: invalid number format model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используя формат числа никак, о чём явно упомянуто в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211):

> Restriction: A group separator **cannot appear to the right of a decimal character** or period in a number format model.

Справа от запятой не может быть групп с их разделителями.
Используйте операции с символьными данными, если это действительно необходимо.  Например:

```
select regexp_replace (str, '(\d{2})', '\1 ', regexp_instr (str, ',')) res from  (
    select to_char(123456.987654, '99G99G99G99D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='', ''') str
    from dual
);
```

> 12 34 56,98 76 54